# How make a automatic include class for multi target (versions) in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swift, version-control, include, target

I'm developing a project, an application, which will have several versions. I will reuse your source code and change only some superficial characteristics.

To help in versioning App, I adopted the solution of using multiple Target's to create different versions of the app, reusing the source code

But I have a question of how should I set up Xcode.

I performed the following operation:

I created a Target Template, possessing all the functionality I need, so whenever I need a new version I duplicate the Target Template.

But when I need to insert a new class, it is not automatically inserted into the target's already created, so I have to tell Xcode to be included the new class in the other target's hand when creating the class.

I would like to know how to set up Xcode so that every time I add a new class in the Target Template, this class is automatically included in other targets.

If someone possessed some guidance on how I can create multiple versions of the same app than with the use of multi targets.

I'm open for suggestions or other solutions!

Thx!

Note. I'm using Xcode 6 and Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up to have a library, (static or shared), target for the common, back end, code, possibly with a test harness in the same "project" and then using the same common back end in all your GUI targets.  You could even have a GUI components library in a similar manner.

Your workflow would then be to develop and test your new back end code and classes then, when you are happy with it, simply rebuild your GUI targets.  If things like menu items are derived from the back end codes published interfaces you would not even have to add the new functionality to them all, it would happen automatically on a rebuild.

Also look at using makefiles for building your code, then you can have a build all at the level above to rebuild all your GUIs.

I am not sure about XCode but a lot of IDEs now support having a super-project, *called different things in different tools*, that consists of multiple projects so that you can simply load your super project and build all in that.

Comment: Thx! i will see how i can make this end test.